# How can I fetch a javascript file and store the response object as an array?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch a javascript file and return the response object as an array. My javascript file is simply an array like ["1", "2", "3", ...] Here is my code right now:

```
function getNames() {
 let data = fetch('/path/to/file')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then(data => {
   console.log(data);
 return data()
 })
 .catch(error => {
   return error;
 });
}
```

I need to find a way to use the data variable outside of the function. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this in node.js?

Comment: Maybe show the exact response for `console.log(data);`

Comment: There are a few questions like this on SO. This one recommends eval() - but you should really google the security implications of using that approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502639/convert-string-loaded-from-text-file-to-an-array-object-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you are not using `fetch` to load a local file, are you?  `fetch` is for executing a ajax request.

Comment: @MrMythical yes

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [];
(
  function() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        data = [...json]
      })
  }

)();

// this is outside - might be empty, if the response does
// not arrive under 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("data in setTimeout", data)
}, 3000)
```

If you want to update the state of your app reactively (based on whether the area has arrived or not), then you should use a reactive library/framework like React, Vue, Angular or Svelte. (Of course, you can create your own reactivity system, but that might be limiting later.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using node.js, so you can use `require()` if you use `module.exports`

`./someFile.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  foo: "bar"
}
```

`./otherFile.js`

```js
const data = require("./someFile.js")
console.log(data.foo) // "bar"
```

If you are asking to get a simple array or object from a file, you should be using `.json` files, and use `require()` just like in the first example. If you want to get the current data, rather than the data you get when you first require it, use the `fs` module

`./array.json`

```json
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "3"
]
```

`./otherFile.js`

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const data = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync("./array.json", "utf8")
)
console.log(data) // [ "1", "2", "3" ]
```